# In draft-js using the staticToolBarPlugin, why does changing styles for selected text move text to new line?

Tags: draftjs, draft-js-plugins

So I will start out with this:

Solar Power

And then I bold, say, Solar, and I get this:

**Solar**

Power

Why does it go into a new line?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was i had global css that messed it up. I had RNW flex styling applying to all elements, including the ones in the wysiwyg.